# How to iterate over Flux and use result from another Mono to filter the Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

```
Mono<MyObj1> mono1 = repository.get(id); // data from reactive mongo
Flux<MyObj2> availabilityInfo = getAvailabilityInfo(); // blocking I/O call
```

What I am trying to achieve is iterate availabilityInfo and need to apply some conditions using mono data and return MyObj2 (which contains delieveryDate and price related information on that date).

I will try to explain in naive coding as below

```
 foreach(MyObj2 obj : availabilityInfo){
      if(MyObj1.getX() && obj.getY()){
         return or break;
      }
  }
```

I want to emit the first element from the flux which satisfies the criteria - `MyObj1.getX() && obj.getY()`, even if there are other elements further in the flux matching the criteria. The criteria is based on the respone from mono which is a reactive mongo db call and few facts from emitted flux element.

Comment: Could you specify what you want to do? For iterating you could use `flatMap` on the flux and for filtering you could use `filter` operator. Please go through the Flux and Mono documentations. They are quite useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to iterate flux and then filter using Mono response like as below.

Comment: You can see my previous comment.

Comment: @uneq25 I clicked on enter very fast. Updated the question now, please take a look at it

Comment: What does this, `MyObj1.getX() && obj.getY()`, mean? doesn't seem like a valid boolean expression. Are you trying to check if they are equal or if they are not null?

Comment: MyObj1 is response from db and X is one boolean attribute, similarly Y is one boolean attribute in MyObj2. Idea here is whether I have to consider that flux element based on condition . I used getX() and getY() as metaphor

Answer (score 7):

Way 1:

```
 Mono<MyObj2> filteredInfo = mono1.flatMapMany(myObj1 -> 
                                        availabilityInfo.filter(myObj1 -> myObj1.getX() && myObj2.getY()).take(1)).single();
```

Way 2:

```
Mono<MyObj2> filteredInfo  = availabilityInfo.collectList().zipWith(mono1).flatMap(tuple -> {
            List<MyObj2> list = tuple.getT1();
            MyObj1 myObj1 = tuple.getT2();
            for(MyObj2 myObj2:list){
                if(myObj1.getX() && myObj2.getY()){
                    return Mono.just(myObj2);
                }
            }
            return Mono.empty();
        });
```

`flatMapMany` is used to create a flux by processing a mono. `filter` takes a predicate, which forms the basis of filtering the flux.

Example:

```
 Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.just(3);
        Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        //Way 1
        Mono<Integer> res = mono.flatMapMany(i -> flux.filter(j -> j % i == 0).take(1)).single();

        res.subscribe(System.out::println);

        //Way 2
       flux.collectList().zipWith(mono).flatMap(tuple -> {
        List<Integer> list = tuple.getT1();
        int x = tuple.getT2();
        for(int y:list){
            if(y%x==0){
                return Mono.just(x);
            }
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Both ways will give me the output:

```
3
```

Comment: Don't we need to subscribe to inner flux by `flatMap`. I tried that but Mono return before flux emits response (WebClient call).

Comment: You can subscribe the `filteredInfo` Flux at the last if you wanna do something with it.

Comment: @akreddy.21 can you clearly specify what you are doing code wise? I have also put an example code for you to visualize things.

Comment: Pretty much the same what you specified in the example only extra thing is as soon as I find 3 I can return I don't need to process remaining flux elements.

Comment: Is there any way to contact you so I can show exactly what I am trying to do. That will be helpful

Comment: So, you want the first element which matches the criteria, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189607/discussion-between-akreddy-21-and-uneq95).